# Create tabular layout with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Currently, I'm struggling with implementing a table-like layout with flexbox. Unlike other solutions, this one doesn't have 4th header for its column. But each item box fills its col.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YDCi.png)
I would appreciate it if you could guide me.

For the header and each item, I used `justify-content: space-between;`, but the header and items won't match, which is normal. Since ***items' length vary...*** I couldn't figure out how to deal with the last col and match it with each item.

[Updated] - A quick demo would be:
HTML: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQY3R.png) SCSS: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GQ4O.png)

Comment: Please update with actual code you have tried so we may best help you FIX it.

Comment: Set `flex-wrap` to `wrap` and define a `width` for your cells to 25%, add an empty div for your ***"imaginary"*** section above the buttons column.

Comment: A tabular layout has a large content area/box with smaller nav boxes above it which act to control what is displayed in the content area/box. I'm thinking what you are after is a table layout?

Comment: The first thing that came to my mind was tabular due to its similarity. You're right. It resembles more to grids :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the ***cell*** or ***flex-child/s*** width to 25% as you have 4 columns. Then set the ***flex-parent*** to `flex-wrap: wrap`, this will force the elements in the flex-parent to wrap.

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cell {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="heading cell">heading</div>
  <div class="heading cell">heading</div>
  <div class="heading cell">heading</div>
  <div class="heading cell"></div>
  <div class="item cell">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item cell">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item cell">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item cell">Button 1</div>
  <div class="item cell">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item cell">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item cell">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item cell">Button 2</div>
  <div class="item cell">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item cell">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item cell">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item cell">Button 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an indirect answer to your question. You say you want a table/tabular but then try to use flexbox - `flex` is a single dimension style whereas `grid` is a 2 dimensional - which is what you say you want.

Here I give an example of a grid with grids inside of it - you can be quite creative.  Note how I also show missing values and "empty" values illustrated with borders just to show what is where.

I also show one button forced to the end of a multiple column block.

```css
body {
  font-soze: 16px;
}

.parent-container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: solid #00FF00 1px;
}

.parent-container .headline {
  border: solid blue 1px;
}

.parent-container .grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "headr" "contentc"
}

.parent-container .grid-container .header-row {
  grid-area: headr;
  border: solid #ff55ff 3px;
}

.parent-container .grid-container .content-container {
  grid-area: contentc;
  border: solid #55ffff 3px;
}

.row-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 2.5rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.row-container>* {
  border: solid 1px #5555FF;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.row-container .too-the-right {
  /* tell it to be multiple columns and then force it to the end of those */
  align-self: center;
  grid-column: span 4;
  justify-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="headline">Imaginary</div>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="header-row row-container">
      <div class="head">Head1</div>
      <div class="head">Head2</div>
      <div class="head">Head3</div>
      <div class="head">Head4</div>
      <div class="head">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
      <div class="content-row row-container">
        <div class="content-item">Me</div>
        <div class="content-item">Fred</div>
        <div class="content-item">Bert</div>
        <div class="content-item">Ernie</div>
        <div class="content-item">imaginary people</div>
        <div class="content-item"><button type="button">Button thing</button></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content-row row-container">
        <div class="content-item">Groucho</div>
        <div class="content-item">Fred</div>
        <div class="content-item">Charlie</div>
        <div class="content-item">
          <div>Fred</div>
          <div>and Wilma</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-item">fake people</div>
        <div class="content-item"><button type="button">Button thing</button></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content-row row-container">
        <div class="content-item">Me</div>
        <div class="content-item">Fred</div>
        <div class="content-item too-the-right"><button type="button">right thing</button></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content-row row-container">
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item">Bert</div>
        <div class="content-item">Cookie Monster</div>
        <div class="content-item"><button type="button">Button thing</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great call, but my objective is to handle this situation with the flexbox feature :)

Comment: Feels like your screwdriver looks like a box-end wrench; try to use the right tool for the job at hand would be my emphasis here - or clearly outline why it cannot be used.

Comment: Yea, your right sir... I will implement it with grids deffo. However, for this particular case, I'm forced to use flexbox. Due to educational purposes :)